# How to make a user control scroll in a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Hi I have created a User Control called WOView that has a panel with Labels and data grids on that I wish to use to display data based on a query. The control is quite large width 960 length 1037. I have set the Panel to Auto Scroll = true. I then created a form with a panel width 1000 length 400 and also a button tha was within the form but not on the panel. The form panel is not docked and has auto scroll = true.

I coded the button as below

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var wov = new WOView();
        gradientPanel1.Controls.Add(wov);
        wov.Visible = true;
        wov.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    }
```

When the button is pressed the user control appears in the panel however it is cut off in legnth and the scroll bars on the panel do not appear to allow me to view the remainder of the control. How do I get the scroll bars to appear in the Form Panel or the user control itself?

Answer (score 1):

Please Ignore I just set the location instead of the dock style and that has worked.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var wov = new WOView();
        gradientPanel1.Controls.Add(wov);
        wov.Visible = true;
        wov.Location=new Point(0,0);
        //wov.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    }
```

Comment: Getting rid of Dock() is the key.  With Dock set to Fill, the UserControl would always match the size of the Panel, therefore never requiring any scrollbars to appear.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround but it's a trick:
first create a property of type bool and name of `isResizeForUC`

```
public bool isResizeForUC { get; set; }
```

after that to the button click handler for the add user control and change `isResizeForUC` to true :

```
isResizeForUC = true;
```

and then you can add your user control into the your scrollable panel

```
MainPanle.Controls.Clear();
MainPanle.Controls.Add(uc);
```

the final code for event click button is :

```
private void createBarname_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   isResizeForUC = true;
   MainPanle.Controls.Clear();
   MainPanle.Controls.Add(uc);
}
```

ok now go to the event `Resize` of your scrollable panel and check the isResizeForUC is true and then set your uc width to your scrollable panel width when form resize :

```
private void MainPanle_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (isResizeForUC)
      {
           uc.Width = MainPanle.Width;
      }
}
```